# Spaces don't count if .slice() ends in a space

Tags: javascript, html, slice

Why does the space not count in `.slice()`. I believe something happens when the last character of `.slice()` is a space, but I'm not sure. It should output `abcd efgh` onto the screen, but instead outputs `abcdefgh`. Can someone explain what's happening here?

Edit: I wasn't clear, but the string is multiline so `textContent` doesn't seem to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>GoP2P</title>
        <style>
        body {
            width: 99%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
            overflow-wrap: break-word;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .terminal {
            color: #21ff28;
            width: 100%;
            height: 90vh;

            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 1.3em;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            padding-right: 1em;

            animation-duration: 0.5s;
            animation-name: colorthing;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-direction: alternate;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>"
        <div class="terminal" id="terminal">
        </div>
        <script>
            var code =`
            abcd efgh
            abcd efgh`;
        </script>
        <script>
            var i = 0;
            document.addEventListener("keydown", function () {
                terminal.innerText += code.slice(i, i+5);
                i += 5;
                if (i > code.length) {
                    i=0;
                }
            });

            setInterval(function (){
                var term = document.getElementById("terminal");
                term.scrollTop = term.scrollHeight;
            }, 100);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you defining `terminal` in your `keydown` handler?

Comment: terminal is the id of a div

Comment: If you use `textContent` instead of `innerText`, it does work. So its `innerText` that's ignoring the spaces not `slice`.

Comment: it works in the scenario of the question, I should update it to more accurately reflect the actual code. the string is multiline, `textContent` doesn't seem to work with that

Comment: @Zanolon `<div>`s don't respect newlines and multiple consecutive spaces. Use [**`<pre>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) instead!

Comment: Got it, thanks so much. It's fixed!